# Prove that triangle AMN has constant perimeter

Tags: geometry

> Take a equilateral triangle .Pick a point D outside of side BC such that BD=CD and $\angle BDC= 120$.There are points M on AB and N on AC such that $\angle MDN=60$.It is required to prove that triangle AMN has constant perimeter irrespective of choice of M and N.

My observations:

> ABCD is cyclic
>   PQ is parallel to MN(but I am not able to prove it.I have drawn many diagrams and in each case it is true)

I tried angle chasing to produce similar and congruent triangle but failed.Any hints?[image]

Note : This question has been asked before but solution was based on solving for a special case.Here I am looking for generalised solution

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Construct DT $\perp $ MN. Note that

$$DT = BD \frac{\cos \alpha_1 }{\cos \alpha_2} = CD \frac{\cos \beta_1 }{\cos \beta_2}$$

From the given, $\alpha_1 + \beta_1 = \alpha_2 + \beta_2=60$ and BD = CD. Then,

$$\frac{\cos \alpha_1 }{\cos \alpha_2} =  \frac{\cos \beta_1 }{\cos \beta_2} =\frac{\cos (60-\alpha_1 )}{\cos (60-\alpha_2)}$$

which leads to $\sin(\alpha_1-\alpha_2) = 0$ and, in turn, $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$. Similarly, $\beta_1=\beta_2$.

Thus, the right triangle pairs MBD-MTD and NCD-NTD are congruent, respectively. As a result, MB = MT, NC = NT and the perimeter of the triangle DMN is equal to $AB+AC$, which is invariant.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\i{\mathbf{i}}$

WLOG, let $O=0,\,R=1$. 
Then the known points are

\begin{align}
A&=\i
,\\
B&=A\exp(\tfrac{2\pi}3\i)=-\tfrac12\,\sqrt3-\tfrac12\,\i
,\\
C&=A\exp(-\tfrac{2\pi}3\i)=\tfrac12\,\sqrt3-\tfrac12\,\i
,\\
D&=-\i
,\\
M&=A\,(1-t)+B\,t
=-\tfrac12\,\sqrt3\,t+\i\,(1-\tfrac32\,t)
,\quad t\in[0,1]
,\\
E&=D+(M-D)\,\exp(-\tfrac\pi3\,\i)
=\sqrt3\,(1-t)
.
\end{align}

Note that for any $t\in[0,1]$,
that is, for any point $M$ on the side $AB$,
the point $E$ is located on the $x$-axis.

The point $N$ is then found at the intersection 
of the lines $AC$ and $DE$,

\begin{align}
N&=AC\cap DE
=
\frac{2\,\sqrt3\,(t-1)}{3\,t-4}
-\i\cdot\frac{3\,t-2}{3\,t-4}
.
\end{align}

The side lengths of  $\triangle AMN$ are
\begin{align}
|AM|=|A-M|&=t\,\sqrt3
,\\
|AN|=|A-N|&=
\frac{4\,\sqrt3\,(1-t)}{4-3\,t}
,\\
|MN|=|M-N|&=
\frac{\sqrt3\,(3\,t^2-6\,t+4)}{4-3\,t}
\end{align}

And the perimeter of $\triangle AMN$ is found as

\begin{align}
p=
|AM|+|AN|+|MN|
&=2\sqrt3
.
\end{align}

Corresponding `Maxima` session log:

```
Maxima 5.38.1 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.12
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1 )     _(z):=conjugate(z)$
(%i2 )     xpoint(z1,z2,z3,z4):=
    ((z1-z2)*(_(z3)*z4-_(z4)*z3)-(z3-z4)*(_(z1)*z2-_(z2)*z1))
    /((z1-z2)*(_(z3)-_(z4))-(z3-z4)*(_(z1)-_(z2)))$
(%i3 )     declare([A,B,C,D,E,M,N],complex)$
(%i4 )     declare([t,AM,AN,MN,p],real)$
(%i5 )     assume(t>0,t<1,(3*t^2-6*t+4)>0)$
(%i6 )     A:%i$
(%i7 )     B:expand(A*exp(%i*2*%pi/3))$
(%i8 )     C:expand(A*exp(-%i*2*%pi/3))$
(%i9 )     D:-A$
(%i10)     M:expand(A*(1-t)+B*t)$
(%i11)     E:factor(D+(M-D)*exp(-%i*%pi/3))$
(%i12)     N:expand(xpoint(A,C,D,E))$
(%i13)     N:factor(realpart(N))+factor(imagpart(N))*%i$
(%i14)     AM:sqrt(factor(realpart((A-M)*_(A-M))))$
(%i15)     AN:sqrt(factor(realpart((A-N)*_(A-N))))$
(%i16)     MN:sqrt(factor(realpart((M-N)*_(M-N))))$
(%i17)     p:AM+AN+MN$
(%i18)     factor(expand(p));
(%o18)                             2 sqrt(3)
```

$\endgroup$

Comment: The sum of measures from A and projection of AM, AN and MN  on AD is always equal to the diameter of circumscribed circle. Isn't this fact enough to conclude that the perimeter of AMN is constant?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Picture.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

COMMENT:

When DM is coincident on DB , MN will be coincident on AB and the measure of the third side AN is zero. That is the perimeter of AMN tends to $2AB$. similar thing happens id N  and M coincide on C and A respectively. When  DM and DN are mirror about AD AMN is equilateral and we have:

$P=\frac{2AB Cos(30^o)}{3}\times 3=2AB$

For other positions of M and N , as can be seen in drawing we always have:

$AB=AN Cos(30^o)+ AD-AM Cos (30^o)$

Or:

$|AN-AM|=\frac{AD-AB}{Cos(30^o)}=constant$

$|AN-AM| Cos(30^o)=(MN) Sin(\angle PNM)=$

Eliminating $|AN-AM|$ we get:

$MN=\frac{(AD-AB) Cos^2567 (30^o)}{Sin (\angle PNM)}$

Seems reasonable to conclude that perimeter of AMN is equal to $2AB$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea of finding cyclic quadrilaterals is good, I'll show a proof only using a bunch of these cyclic quadrilaterals. But first,  I need some labels, so

Let $R$ the intersection of $MD$ and $BC$.
Let $S$ the intersection of $ND$ and $BC$.

Now I can start with the proof:

1. You found out that $\angle BMD=\angle BSD=30+\alpha$. That means that $BMSD$ is cyclic. In particular $\angle MSD=180-\angle MBD=90$
2. Similarly, $\angle CND=\angle CRD=90-\alpha$. That means that $CNRD$ is cyclic. In particular $\angle NRD=180-NCD=90$
3. Since $\angle MSN=\angle NRM=90$, we have that $MRSN$ is cyclic.
4. Since $MRSN$ is cyclic we have $\angle RMN=\angle RSD=30+\alpha$ and $\angle MNS=\angle SRD=90-\alpha$. [This also proves that $PQ$ is also parallel to $MN$]
5. Construct $T$ in $MN$ such that $DT\perp MN$.
6. Note by symmetry of the quadrilaterals $BMTD$ and $DTNC$ that $MT=MB$ and $TN=NC$.
7. Conclude that $AM+MN+NA=AM+MT+TN+NA=AM+MB+NC+CA=AB+AC$